# Disable commenting-ability on a photo-by-photo basis

Tags: facebook, privacy

I'd like to disable the commenting function for all of my friends for some of my photos but not for all of them or my status updates which is the only privacy control panel I can find. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe you can do it by album I an not sure about by photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook privacy settings do not allow you to disable comments on a specific photo or album. You can exclude certain friends from commenting on (all) posts, which includes photos, but it will also keep them from commenting on status updates and other wall posts.

The closest you can get to what you want is to put all the "no comment" photos into one or more albums, then hide those albums from the people you don't want commenting on them. However, if you still want them to be able to see the photos, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't. But you can just limit them to your "friends", and not to "friends of friends" or "everybody".

1. Go to "Account Settings"
2. Click on "Followers"
3. Click the "Edit" on the "Follower Comment"
4. Click the drop down arrowhead and select/change to "Friends"

...and you're done.

Otherwise, just go to your photo and block those specific people whom you don't want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only change privavy settings or view order but not prevent commenting only. And this depend on the type of album

I found out there are 5 (up until now) different Photo Albums on Facebook:

1. Made and used by Facebook like Background pictures
   Not able to change order ito set any privacy setting. All is public.
2. Made and used by Facebook like Profile or Timeline pictures
   Not able to change order but user can set privacy on photo tot photo basis.
3. Made by Instagram, iPhone or iOS
   You cán change the order but can only set the privacy for the entire album and user can not add photo's manually or move picture here from other albums.
4. Made and named by yourself
   You cán change the order, can only set the privacy for the entire album but you cán  add photo's manually or move picture here from other albums
5. And one single video album made by Facebook. 
   You can set individual privacy settings here. No changing order or moving to other places. Only edit or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Of course we can do it; follow these simple steps:

1. Open your photo album;
2. Then open that particular photo;
3. Select the option available at bottom of the image (down arrow symbol);
4. Then select **Custom** to customise the setting or select **Only me** if you want to see this photo individually.

Comment: The OP wants to disable comments on a specific photo or album.

Comment: +1, this is not an answer to the original question